# want to disable the radio button appearing on spinner after selection

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Spinner with radio button]

Hi friends wanna remove the radio button appearing on spinner.. Which is increasing the layout size of my dialog..  Thanks in advance..

Comment: Looks like you've missed the image link. Please edit/update it.

Comment: Sorry but i cant upload image.. as it says you acquire atleast 10 points... and i dont hv it :(

Comment: upload your image to any free image hosting server and paste the link here. http://postimage.org/

Comment: http://s16.postimage.org/gks053rdx/Untitled.png  please check this image... the radio btn appearing in front of "per 1 hour" want to remove it.. thaks for replying Ghost and Waqas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set your spinner's adapter as follow:

```
adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]{"1", "2"});
adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark it as answer if it worked well for you :)

Comment: @Waqas- please help me in how to add the comments on others question..instead of answer??

Comment: you need to earn (i guess) atleast 50 points to start commenting on question/answers. At this point, you may earn points by asking good questions or answer few questions. There might be other ways too, which i dont at the moment. Refer to the help section for further details

Comment: ok thanks and one more help please :) how to get the whole code of formats like this link.. https://github.com/ariefbayu/android-list-form-db  because going to each file and copying it is a tedious task..

Comment: you may get it through your repository client or the other way is to download the entire project from site. If you look closer above the `Files` tab, so there exists a button `Zip`. Click that button to download the entire project

Comment: and how to do in this case http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/#android%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fapps%2Fiosched%2Fui

Comment: use Checkout option and the provided link

Answer (score 4):

For this you need to change your Spinner Style

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Registration.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Your Array);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```